# Fast way to check if string is `mostly` capital

Tags: c#, string, performance, uppercase

I'm writing a bot in C# for a chat room and I want to detect if a message contains too many capital letters. A message contains too many capital letters if its total uppercase letter count exceeds `one-third` of its total message length and if its total length is greater than `13`. This is to prevent smaller messages from being flagged.

Right now I am looping through each character and seeing if it is uppercase. This is fine for a reasonably lengthed message. However, if you get a spammer or troll, they will not always post reasonably lengthed messages. The maximum character limit is `2000` and I cannot change this. With my method, it starts stalling around `500+` characters. This gives the spammer enough time to paste the message and send it again, effectively flooding the chat while the bot struggles to keep up.

The code I have currently:

```
bool isMostlyUpper = (message.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c)) >= message.Length * 0.3f) && message.Length > 13;
```

I can't compare the message to `string.ToUpper()` because I still want to detect if the message is mostly uppercase as opposed to all uppercase.

Is there a way to do this without looping over each char? Or a way to get to the result faster? I can add checks to see if the message is `> 500` but sometimes there are `500+` long messages that are okay to pass through.

Does anyone have any clever solutions? Thanks.

Comment: This is probably going to take some trial and error. Why not try the first 100 characters, see if it's working. If not try the first 200, 300, etc. Another method would be to see what's actually out there. Go find some spambots and see if the above methods I listed would do anything, or if even checking 500+ would do anything.

Comment: Your solution seems incredibly quick, how could the spammer send data over a network faster than that code?

Comment: Your code will always check the full length of the string to get the full count but you only need to know if you reach your limit - so how about a normal for loop stopping when the count gets to 1/3 length? You could also dynamically change the length of the message to check to _"message.Length - (LimitChars - CountSoFar)"_ - where limit chars is 1/3 length. No point carrying on when you know you cant exceed th limit.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but when I was testing I could send over more than 10 `1000` length messages per 1 message deleted by the bot. It may slow it down because of the build up of messages? Each time a new one is sent it begins another asynchronous loop. And the cool-down time in the chat is not fast enough to prevent this kind of flooding.

Comment: Something to take into consideration: If your chat is being spammed to that degree, there's already a problem. If you have anti-message spamming control, this performance issue becomes far less of an issue.

Comment: It is more a precaution in the [off chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) that it could happen.

Comment: first of all, prevent pasting. second, there are probably better methods than always looping through the whole string. for example, you could play some statistics (this would need fine tuning based on particular use cases): you could pick random N characters, on random M positions (both, N and M being dependant on whole string length). After you probe that, you have some treshold set which says how many random uppercase chars as a percentage of whole string length makes message suspicious and if it exceeds treshold then you do deep check.

Comment: I really doubt this code is your bottle neck.  To count the number of upper case characters in a string of 1 million characters on my machine takes about 8 ms.  So for a message of 1000 characters you're talking maybe 8 µs to count the upper case characters.  There's no way this is what's slowing down your app.

Comment: Kyle, I just set up a new project with only my original code and it is indeed working as intended. You are correct to assume there is something else in the way. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break out of your foor loop when you reach your condition you will save some time in some cases

```
int count = 0;
float maxLenght = message.Length * 0.3f;
bool isMostlyUpper = false;

foreach (char c in message)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        count++;
    }

    if(count >= maxLenght)
    {
        isMostlyUpper = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

You could also keep track of the last message that was flagged and compare it to the new message received so it would stop people spamming the same message and you wouldn't have to recalculate the same message multiple times.

Comment: See the further addition to my comment above - you can also stop search when you know it is impossible to exceed the cut off number. For example, if you get to (message.Length - maxLength) & haven't had any upper case messages - you know the string is mostly Lowercase - so no point carrying on searching.

Comment: @PaulF isn't that the same condition, just mathematically flipped? If you have 10 upper of 30 -> Mostly Upper - your suggestion: If you have 0 and 19 left -> Not mostly upper. So this is just a question of `<1-0.66` or `>0.33` i'd say. ofc. performance might vary depending on the position of upper characters in the string. But on average i'd say tracking both cases is more expensive than having the rare cases of only upper case letters at the end of a string.

Comment: I think there is a (calculateable) point on which the equation flips. If your messages are SHORTER than 30 on average, look at Uppercase-Letters or if they are longer, look at remaining characters (or vice versa) - but never the less, talking about micro-seconds here.

Comment: @dognose I was also thinking keeping track of the last message flagged and then comparing it to the new message received so it would stop people spamming the same message not to sure if it would help.

Comment: @dognose: Instead of using a foreach loop, use a for loop with end condition set to a variable initialised to _message.Length-maxLength_ for each uppercase letter found as well as incrementing count, increment the end position. So all you have really added is a single integer increment overhead per Uppercase character to the loop. If the majority of messages do not have more than 1/3 uppercase letters - then I believe there would be a time saving - plus for loop is likely to be faster in this situation.

Comment: @dognose: I also agree we are talking microseconds - but I think that should also apply to the original LINQ code - I know LINQ is quite often significantly slower than writing the equivalent code - but don't really understand why it would be a problem unless there are a significant number of messages arriving per second - if that is the case then OP has a completely different problem that speeding up this bit of code is not going to fix.

Comment: As @PaulF said, you can stop sooner when you know there aren't enough characters left to reach the threshold. For example, in a 30 character message, if count is still 0 after looking at 21 characters, you can stop.

Comment: The `count >= maxLenght` condition is doing a floating point comparison. This can probably be done faster by using an integer comparison. Use `int maxLength = message.Length * 3 / 10;`

Comment: Also, testing that `count >= maxLength` needs only be done if and when you incremented the count. Move this test into the statement block of the other if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Start skipping characters when the message gets too long

```
private static bool IsMostlyUpper (string message)
{
    if (message.Length > 13) {
        int step = 1 + message.Length / 100; // integer division.
        // 1 for message length < 100
        // 2 for message length < 200
        // 3 for message length < 300

        int limit = message.Length / step / 3;
        int upperCase = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i += step) {
            if (Char.IsUpper(message[i])) {
                upperCase++;
                if (upperCase >= limit) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use a greater divisor to test a bigger fraction of the characters.

---

If you think that a very smart bot can trick your algorithm, you could also create a random divisor

```
private static Random _random = new Random(); // static field
```

Create the divisor with

```
int divisor = _random.Next(150, 200);
int step = 1 + message.Length / divisor;
```

---

But this is a lot of complication to only save a few microseconds!

Comment: This won't work since it would be possible to create a message with arbitrarily high percentages of upper case characters that this method will say is all lower case.

Comment: If you want to construct such a message you need to know this algorithm. How should a spammer know it? You could also create a random a divisior like this: `random.Next(150, 200)`